# Alt-tab in Windows 8.1 looks like Windows XP

Tags: windows-8.1, alt-tab

I have a new Lenovo laptop with Windows 8.1, and the alt-tab dialog looks like Windows XP.

Like this: [image]

instead of like this: [image]

It also contains a bunch of default icons that don't display a name. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I restarted my computer to install some updates and it went back to normal. I don't know if the restart or the updates are what fixed it. I guess I'll accept this answer unless somebody comes around with a better explanation.

Comment: Restarting windows is the first thing I do when weirdness appears in the operating system, sometimes it takes 2 or 3 restarts to correct it, consider this a Windows "Feature".