# My Alt + Tab menu looks and works oddly

Tags: windows, windows-8, alt-tab

I've had an issue for a while now which makes my <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> not work and function correctly.

I can't:

- Click on it
- It displays items which are supposed to be hidden (?)
- It doesn't use the Aero theme

I've tried the following:

- Rebooting
- Closing `dwm.exe`
- Updating Windows.

If there is a need for OS: I'm running Win 8.1 x64.

Example:

[image: screenshot of alt-tab]

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you saying you have the same problem as mentioned in the question you linked to? You can upload a screenshot to imgur.com and add link to it in your question.

Comment: Trying to printscreen just closes the alt tab. Also it's not the same but worse.

Comment: You'll need to use a camera then, because it's difficult to understand what you're experiencing.

Comment: I've added an example I found via google. If this is not enough I'll take a picture with a camera.

Comment: Well looks basically like a duplicate of [Alt-tab in Windows 8.1 looks like Windows XP](http://superuser.com/questions/870382/alt-tab-in-windows-8-1-looks-like-windows-xp). Try restarting the [DWM](http://superuser.com/questions/656162/windows-8-restart-desktop-window-manager). Also check if it works properly with a new local user account.

Comment: It happens on my machine too and quite often especially when in-game. Seems Microsoft didn't remove the old dialog and now it interferes with the new one.

Comment: Restarting the DWM doesn't fix the problem unfortunately.

It does indeed look like a duplicate. This has been like this for a while now. But updates haven't fixed it.

Comment: Also duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/770898/windows-8-1-alt-tab-bug-in-specific-programs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

> Please follow these simple steps:
>
> 1. Type `regedit` in RUN or Start search box and press Enter. It'll open Registry Editor.
> 2. Now go to the following key:
>
>    ```
>    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer
>    ```
> 3. In the right-side pane, create a new DWORD `AltTabSettings` and set its value to `1`
>
>    [image: screenshot of regedit]
> 4. That's it. Log off or restart Explorer as mentioned here to apply changes.
>
> Now whenever you'll press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> keys together, it'll show Windows
>   XP styled classic <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> Switcher screen instead of the new screen.
>
> 5. To restore the new <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> Switcher screen, simply delete the `AltTabSettings` DWORD created in step 3. Log off and login again to
>      take effect.

[[Tip] Get Windows XP Style Classic “Alt+Tab” Switcher Screen in Windows Vista and Later](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-get-windows-xp-styled-classic-alttab-screen-in-windows-vista-and-7/)

(Or rather, try the reverse of that)

Comment: This got it working. The reverse that is. I never set this though so I find it odd it ws changed.

Comment: I just restarted Explorer and it worked. That DWORD was not set.